# Magento 2 Modified Product Cache file not being used

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, product-images

Why are optimized files that I manually add to "pub/media/catalog/product/cache" not being served.

I have optimized product images that are much smaller than those automatically created in "pub/media/catalog/product/cache". So I copied over the files in the cache, but these files are still not loading in the web browser.

See Image:

[image]

What do I need to do to make my manually added files to cache be served in a web browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent loading product images from Magento 2 cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183863/how-to-prevent-loading-product-images-from-magento-2-cache)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I missed one step to make this all work:

```
systemctl restart nginx php7.0-fpm redis 'varnish*'
```